# Rewrite Rule Redirect Sub Folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm stuck on how to write a dynamic re-write rule or if it's even possible. The original path the files will not exist at but will exist at the new path as physical files. The first, second and 3rd directories in the request will be static except the 2nd directory which can be any integer. The 3rd directory can be one of 2 choices but does not impact the final path.

`/test/1/name/folder/test.js
/anotherpath/1/folder/test.js`

`/test/44/name/test.js
/anotherpath/44/test.js`

`/test/55/name/folderagain/txt.txt
/anotherpath/55/folderagain/txt.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague in what it actually is you are looking for. Especially because you do not post any own attempt which would demonstrate what it actually is you want to implement.

So I have to guess a bit, but I assume that is more or less what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?test/(\d+)/[^/]+/(.+)$ /anotherpath/$1/$2 [END]
```

That rule will work likewise in the http server's host configuration or in dynamic configuration files (.htaccess style files), if those are enabled.

In case you receive a http status 500 using that rule ("internal server error") chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. In that case try replacing the `[END]` flag with the older `[L]` flag, it should work the same in this case. You will find according notes in the http servers error log file in that case.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).